# cardboard display problems in S4 mini

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have a problem with my GT-I9195L. When I open any cardboard application the two screens appear incomplete. I have no idea what could be the problem.

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=ADCC2C4A5DC035DF%216187&cid=ADCC2C4A5DC035DF&group=0&parId=ADCC2C4A5DC035DF%21408&o=OneUp

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware/software tech support.

Comment: I'm trying to program for cardboard, but I can't since I have this issue

Answer (score 0):

The two screens are not incomplete - the effect you see is a result of distortion correction being applied to the image so it's seen correctly in the cardboard. If you'd like to learn more:

https://photographylife.com/what-is-distortion

Comment: do you mean that distortion correction is that you can see a hat with one eye and nothing with other?